# Phone number with regex in ios with + and -(separator) in ios

Tags: ios

I Want to implement validation in phone number which contain only number,+ and -(separator). I am writing the following regex but its not working.
Please provide me the soutions. Thanks in advance.

```
NSString *phoneRegex = @"^((\\+)|(00))[0-9,\-]{6,15}$"
```

Comment: Please provide a few examples of valid and invalid phone numbers.

Comment: I want only the the phone number regex which contain only number + and -(separator) where + is at first place and no particular place for  - (separator) .